# What is this Script Font?

Tags: font-identification

I cannot seem to find this, I was told by my client that its called "customised" but its no where to be found. Tried identifont and What the font, but its too complicated to break down.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other examples of the font to compare individual letters to see if the letters are consistent or not? Looks like a font written using a tablet.

Comment: it is a font, the client wants to create a monogram for it, "CV" Customised Vehicles. But he doesn't have the font used. 

Its not hand made. Its an edited font.

Comment: @AasimAzam if it's an edited font it's going to be very hard to detect. Is contacting the initial designer not an option?

Comment: Tried to contact him .... to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Xtreem Fat](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mawns/xtreem/) by Mans Greback via Myfonts

[image]